# P4API.NET compatibility in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, p4api.net

we've a service written in C# (dotnetcore 2.2) that uses P4API.NET library for performing perforce related operations. recently we migrated and hosted the same service in linux machine. after this we're getting below error message,

**Unable to load shared library 'p4bridge.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libp4bridge.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

any help around this would be much appreciated!

Comment: this could be because it can only be run on a windows machine. Have you checked the p4api documentation?